# Unexpected Token

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I am new to TypeScript.
Actually I want to create an array of user objects. I am using contextAPI.
I want to concatenate the uploadState details into setUser but it shows the error unexpected token in setUser. I don't know what to do can someone please help me.

This is my contextAPI code.

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { UserType } from "../Reducers/Upload";

type UserContextProviderType = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const intionalState: UserType[] = [
  { name: "", phoneNumber: "", partyName: "", userImage: "" } as UserType,
];

type UserContextType = {
  user: UserType[];
  setUser: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserType[]>>;
};
export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType | null>(null);

export const UserState = ({ children }: UserContextProviderType) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType[]>(intionalState);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And This is my UserType

```
export type UserType = {
    name: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    partyName: string;
    userImage: string;
};
```

This is my upload file. Inside the `context.setUesr` near `...context.user?` it shows unexpected token. I want to add uploadState to user.

```
import { useContext, useReducer, useRef, useState } from "react";
import InputField from "../components/InputField";
import Button from "../components/Button";
import Image from "../components/Image";
import CommonStyle from "../Style/CommonStyle.module.css";
import UploadStyle from "../Style/UploadDetails.module.css";
import { intionalUploadState, uploadReducer } from "../Reducers/UploadReducer";
import defaultPic from "../assets/defaultPic.png";
import { UserContext } from "../context/UserContext";


export default function UploadDetails() {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string>(defaultPic);
  const [uploadState, dispatch] = useReducer(
    uploadReducer,
    intionalUploadState
  );

  const context = useContext(UserContext)

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    context?.setUser(prev => {return [...prev, {...context.user? ,context.user?.concate[uploadState]}]})

  };

  
const imageUpload = () => {
    inputRef.current?.click();
  };

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    switch (event.target.name) {
      case "name":
        dispatch({ type: event.target.name, payload: event.target.value });
        break;
      case "phoneNumber":
        dispatch({ type: event.target.name, payload: event.target.value });
        break;
      case "partyName":
        dispatch({ type: event.target.name, payload: event.target.value });
        break;
      case "userImage":
        dispatch({ type: event.target.name, payload: event.target.value });
        setImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files![0]));
        console.log(uploadState);
        break;
      default:
        return uploadState;
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={UploadStyle.container}>
        <h2 className={CommonStyle.header} style={{marginTop: "1rem"}}>Enter Details</h2>
        <div className={UploadStyle.detailsSection}>
          <div className={UploadStyle.textSection}>
            <InputField
              type="text"
              name="candidateName"
              placeholder="Enter Name"
              styles={CommonStyle.commonInput}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
            <InputField
              type="text"
              name="phoneNumber"
              placeholder="Enter PhoneNumber"
              styles={CommonStyle.commonInput}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
            <InputField
              type="text"
              name="PartyName"
              placeholder="Enter Party Name"
              styles={CommonStyle.commonInput}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={UploadStyle.imageSection}>
            <input
              type="file"
              name="imageInput"
              className={UploadStyle.imageInput}
              ref={inputRef}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <Image source={image} styles={UploadStyle.imageUpload} />
            <Button
              name="Upload Image"
              styles={UploadStyle.button}
              type="button"
              handleSubmit={imageUpload}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button name="Submit" styles={CommonStyle.button} type="button" handleSubmit={handleClick}/>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

and this is my reducer file.

```
import { UserType } from "./Upload";

export const intionalUploadState: UserType = {
  name: "",
  phoneNumber: "",
  partyName: "",
  userImage: "",
};

type UploadStateType = {
  type: "name" | "phoneNumber" | "partyName" | "userImage";
  payload: string;
};

export const uploadReducer = (
  state: UserType,
  action: UploadStateType
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "name":
      return { ...state, name: action.payload };
    case "phoneNumber":
      return { ...state, phoneNumber: action.payload };
    case "partyName":
      return { ...state, partyName: action.payload };
    case "userImage":
      return { ...state, userImage: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

How can I fix this error and add the uploadState to user.

Comment: As far as I know `context.user?` is not valid syntax. You should omit `?` or use the null-coalescing operator `??`.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two issues with your code;

- Optional chaining and spread syntax is wrong
- The method to `concat` is spelt wrong (its not `concate`)

**This**:

```
context?.setUser(prev => {return [...prev, {...context.user?, context.user?.concate[uploadState]}]})
```

**Should be this**:

```
context?.setUser(prev => [...prev, uploadState])
```

That's why we just spread the previous state prev and append `uploadState` to it.

**Your `handleClick` function will now look like this:**

```
const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  context?.setUser(prev => [...prev, uploadState]);
};
```